# Paginate in GSP with an array List

Tags: grails, pagination

How can I use the `<g:paginate\>` tag to paginate an array list in a table?

I have this in my controller

```
def selectevents(){
def events = DomainEvents.findAllByMonth('June')   
[events:events, count:events.size()]

}
```

And I have this in My GSP:

```
<table id="results-table" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%">
<thead>
<tr style="background: #d3d3d3;">
    <th style="width: 3%;text-align: center;"></th>
    <th style="width: 10%;text-align: center;">Name</th>        
</tr>
</thead>
<g:each in="${events}" status="i" var="eventsInstance">
    <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}">
    <td>-</td>
    <td>${eventsInstance?.Name}</td>

    </tr>
</g:each>
```

and then this:

```
<g:paginate next="Forward" prev="Back" maxsteps="5" controller="Controller" action="selectevents" total="${count}" />
```

But the pagination tag doesn't appear. I want to make a pagination to get 5 rows per page,  some one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is calling `DomainEvents.findAllByMonth('June')` which is returning all of the events for the month of June.  You only want to retrieve a subset of 5 of them and then use pagination to navigate around those subsets.

You probably want something like this in your controller:

```
def showEvents() {
    params.max = 5
    def count = DomainEvents.countByMonth('June')
    def events = DomainEvents.findAllByMonth('June', params)
    [domainEventsInstanceCount: DomainEvents.count(), domainEventsInstanceList: events]
}
```

And then something like this in your GSP:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <g:paginate total="${domainEventsInstanceCount ?: 0}" />
</div>
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Notice that `DomainEvents.countByMonth('June')` is required as you don't want to refer to `events.size()` as that is only going to include 5 elements.  You want the 5 elements to render but also want to know the total number so the paginate tag knows how many steps are involved in navigating over all of them.